# Error while paginating html in UIWebView using css Multicolumns

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad

Here is my Problem:

I'm currently writing an ebook reader in objective-c and want to use multicolumns to paginate my xhtml file in my webview.
Unfortunately when I add Multicolumns to my css, my html seems to be only 2 "pages" long, which is exactly the first two

tags.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?.

here is the code with which i inject the new settings into my css:

```
NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

NSString *addCSSRule =  @""
    "function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
        "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
            "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"       // For Internet Explorer
        "} else {"              
            "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
            "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
        "}" // endif mySheet.addRule
    "}"; // end addCSSRule()    
NSString *insertColumns = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('div', 'height: 370px; -webkit-column-width: 320px');"];



[wv_reader stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

[wv_reader stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

[wv_reader stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertColumns];
```

For scrolling i use the following code:

```
int i_scrollTo = ([AppState sharedInstance].i_myselectedPage -1) * wv_reader.frame.size.height;
[wv_reader stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0,%d);", i_scrollTo]];
```

which works perfect if i don't set Multicolumns in my css.

I also tested, if my html is somehow cut off after adding multicolumns, but a NSLog of the content of the webview showed, that the whole ebook is loaded.
When getting the maximum scrollheight though i found out, that without columns it is **79061**, and after inserting columns into my css it is reduced to **424** for some reason i don't know.

Can somebody please help me to fix this? I'm working on this problem for about a week now and couldn't find a solution.

Thx in advance.
Maverick

*UPDATE****
Scrolling horizontally doesn't work either, because my document.scrollWidth is stuck to the width of my Columns, which is pretty odd I think.

Comment: int totalWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] intValue];
 pagesInCurrentSpineCount = (int)((float)totalWidth/webView.bounds.size.width);

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader

Maybe this sample can help you ?

Comment: Wow. Didn't think i'd get an answer to this after all this time.
I'll have a look into it as soon as i've time for it. Thx for the link. I've found a workaround for this problem a while ago and totally forgot to post the answer here. :)

Comment: @Maverick1st I am also facing this issue if you get answer please share

Comment: hmm. This project is so old, i just cannot say, if the problem can still be solved the way i did it. As soon as i have time to look up the solution i will post it here.

Comment: @Maverick1st please check this link   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332081/need-the-web-view-pagination